# How to detect a youtube page has changed on an extension?

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

I'm developing an extension where I display some content on the sidebar based on specific youtube videos. I have these checks

```
  // get message on tab change
  browser.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
    browser.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function (tab) {
      GetInitialInfo(tab);
    });
  });
  // get message on page load
  browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
      GetInitialInfo(tab);
    }
  });
  // // on window load
  window.onload = function () {
    browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      GetInitialInfo(tabs[0]);
    });
  };
```

But none of them seem to detect when the youtube video changes. (The ajax bit).

I want `GetInitialInfo()` to run on: tab change, page change, youtube video change.

I think it works on tab change and page change (I've tested this for so long I'm no longer sure) But because youtube video pages change ajax style (or however) I don't know how to detect that.

Comment: what about checking the URL change in address bar

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam how would I do that? I tried `window.addEventListener('popstate'..)` in the content-script and didn't do anything, I added it in the background script and did nothing.

Comment: What about using the `tab.url` method, and checking if it changes or not

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam that's the thing in the above code, inside `GetInitialInfo` the `tab.url` doesn't change when  youtube changes its popstate or whatever they do